# Linearity Assumption - What is the difference between the "Deviation from Linearity" and "Linearity" Statistic in SPSS?

Tags: regression, spss

I'm trying to assess whether a variable has a linear relationship to a DV. However there is a weak relationship, so assessing the scatterplot for linearity is quite difficult.

I came across this statistical linearity test on SPSS (Compare Means> Means> Options [Select "Test for Linearity"]> Run) and I'm wondering whether it would work as an alternative to scatterplots?

Once run you get the table shown below. I'm a bit confused about what the Deviation from Linearity and the Linearity statistic mean in this table?

Am I looking for a significant Linearity statistic to pass the linear assumption for regression, or am I looking for a non-significant statistic for Deviation from Linearity to pass the assumption?

[image]

Comment: *No* test is a suitable alternative to a scatterplot.  The scatterplot has the potential to reveal data characteristics that neither you nor the test anticipated.  IMHO, good statisticians *always* view their data, even if they don't display them or even report doing that in a paper.  As far as your question goes, the place to look for an answer is the SPSS documentation.  I think the df for "Deviation from Linearity" gives a strong clue about what is meant :-).